# Tag merge request: [autobahn] and [autobahnws]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

As discussed on [this project page](http://autobahn.ws/python/#community), [autobahn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autobahn) and [autobahnws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autobahnws) are used as synonyms by people asking about the Autobahn project.

I suggest [autobahn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autobahn) should be canonical tag with [autobahnws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autobahnws) as synonym.

Comment: Mandatory background music https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iukUMRlaBBE

Comment: [I'd prefer the 22 minutes version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e11h73WhqK4). Didn't even know there was a Radio edit version until now.

Comment: Is it just me, or does `autobahnws` look like a typo?

Comment: Entertaining discussion - can we also discuss any objections to getting this merge done?

Comment: @dorukayhan The 'ws' is short for 'WebSocket' because autobahn is a websocket library.

Comment: Synonym was proposed by oberstet, Jul 31 '14; Approved now.